# How to Check-in in TFS to Development | Production?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

need some explanation or procedure for tfs usage. I surf in internet cant get. we are the 7 team members including 1 tester. whenever people are checked in that will be updated on work-space server. When I get the latest version all files are included. I want what are the files are finished their testing after only to production.

**how to check-in in tfs for development or production?**

Comment: Branch your code in a "development" and a "production" branch. You checkin into the "development"-branch and once your changes have been approved you can merge your changes into the "production"-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Get Specific Version feature in TFS instead of Get latest version. Get a specific changeset by changesetId, labels, time or workspace version. (In Source Control Explore, right click the files you want to get, choose **Advanced**-->**Get Specific Version**)

Like that mentioned in the comment above, you could use Branches for Development, Testing and Deployment. [Branch folders and files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files) into several branches to manage your code and project better.

I suggest that you could start to use **Code Review** feature in TFS. All your tester and developers could add comments in the [code review request](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs#request-a-code-review). This is for is those code you're not sure if it is fine, submit a code review before check in. You could refer to that code review request to find if those files are fine.